# How to inject values from another properties file into ValidationMessages.properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-validator, properties-file

I need to change the `@NotNull` message used by hibernate-validator.

Have successfully done this using a line in ValidationMessages.properties, e.g: `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=my validation message`.

However, this isn't quite what's needed. Will spare the details about why but all these messages should originate from a single messages.properties file, whose purpose is not only for validation but other messages as well.

Let's say messages.properties initially contains a single property `CCCI_0001=my generic message`. Is it possible to somehow substitute this property value from messages.properties into a placeholder in ValidationMessages.properties?

Comment: Nope, sorry, all Hibernate validation messages must be declared inside the annotation, and cannot be dynamically injected using the @Value annotation. You may be able to write a custom annotation wrapper that allows you to inject values into the error messages, but by default they can't be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is bootstrap your `ValidatorFactory` with a custom `MessageInterpolator`. If you are happy to use a Hibernate Validator specific feature, you can use a `ResourceBundleLocator` - see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-message-interpolation. It looks somewhat like this:

```
Validator validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator(
                new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
                        new PlatformResourceBundleLocator( "MyMessages" )
                )
        )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```